# How to save flutter Agora RTC Engine video chat to local storage?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, record, agora.io

I am using [Agora RTC Engine](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine#-installing-tab-) in my flutter app for video chat.

I want to record and save that video chat also to the local storage of mobile.
Any idea how to do that? I am looking for the code from where **Agora** is uploading video frames to server.

Comment: have you found any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Agora provide multiple solutions to save the video stream directly to the cloud but doesn't offer a inApp solution to save it on local storage. In order to do that, i suggest to use this package (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screen_recording) to capture and record the video and audio from the mobile screen.

Comment: Thanks @Nabil , but the plugin you are talking about  is not stable yet , I have tried it .
Did you use that plugin ?

Comment: Yes i used it for the same purpose.

Comment: I have tried , but that plugin is not working...
How you make it workable @Nabil ?

Comment: Have you assigned the necessary permissions, add a permissions handeler plugin  or try to do that manually.

Comment: I did that manually , except screen_recording permission ,
How to grant screen_recording permission ?

Comment: try the solution explained on this link: https://github.com/Isvisoft/flutter_screen_recording/issues/10

Comment: It looks like this package doesn't work if you'd like to record sound as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether Agora could let you save in your local storage.

But this one should help,
https://pub.dev/packages/ed_screen_recorder

Comment: How do you enableAudio to true on ed_sound_recorder? I tried it and it works but can't enableAudio because it gives errors